# Eclipse not launching for MacOS Sierra

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have brand new 2016 MacBook running the latest MacOS Sierra and I'm trying to install Eclipse Luna for building one of our Legacy Applications.

On my personal 2013 Macbook running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 I was able to simply download the eclipse tar and unpackaged it, open the eclipse folder, click the Eclipse.app and it launched perfectly.

However, on my work laptop, I have downloaded the exact same eclipse tar and unpacked it, but when I launch Eclipse.app I immediately get an error saying "Eclipse has quit unexpectedly"

If I open the package contents of Eclipse.app and go to Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/ and run the eclipse.exe located there, then it will open a terminal window and launch Eclipse normally.

I have never encountered this before and cannot find any good references to this issue online.

Is anyone aware of what the cause might be?

I have JDK 6 and 8 installed at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ 1.6.0.jkd & jdk1.8.0_121.jdk

Comment: Eclipse Mars is the latest, by the way

Comment: Neon is the latest. Not Mars. Also, newer versions of Eclipse can only run on Java 8 or higher. We have legacy applications that were built on Java 6 and are not going to be converted any time soon. So we stick to the version of Eclipse that the application was built in.

Answer (score 13):

Found the solution on Eclipse forums.

Sometimes with eclipse you have to un-package the tar files directly into your Applications folder in order for it install properly. Simply dragging/copying the eclipse folder into your Applications directly will not work from time to time.

After running:

```
tar -xf *.tar --directory /Applications
```

Eclipse installed and would launch properly.

Comment: Worked for me :-).

Comment: That worked for me also, Thanks. 
I wanted to have multiple eclipse versions so I created a folder with the version name, like, 
tar -xf eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz -C /Applications/eclipse-luna-sr2